# Where to read about Lord Dhanvantari?

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, dhanvantari

Lord Dhanvantari appears in the churning of the ocean by the demigods and demons. Srimad Bhagavatam Purana describes his appearance as follows:

> SB 8.8.33 — He was dressed in yellow garments and wore brightly polished earrings made of pearls. The tips of his hair were anointed with oil, and his chest was very broad. His body had all good features, he was stout and strong like a lion, and he was decorated with bangles. In his hand he carried a jug filled to the top with nectar.
>   SB 8.8.34 — This person was Dhanvantari, a plenary portion of a plenary portion of Lord Viṣṇu. He was very conversant with the science of medicine, and as one of the demigods he was permitted to take a share in sacrifices.
>   SB 8.8.35 — Upon seeing Dhanvantari carrying the jug of nectar, the demons, desiring the jug and its contents, immediately snatched it away by force.

I am interested in finding how when did churning of the ocean happen. So I am wondering 
1. Which chapters in various puranas talk about Dhanvantari incarnation? 
2. What are some other sources of information available to read on Lord Dhanvantari?

Comment: This link provides many informations: www.google.com/amp/s/topyaps.com/facts-about-dhanvantari/amp/

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9369/what-is-the-story-of-dhanvantari-the-incarnation-of-vishnu

Comment: Thank you @Partha . The other Q&A has some puranic threads which I would follow. I am looking for more.